# Torch: how to concatenate tensors of different sizes?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two tensors:

```py
rc of size: torch.Size([128, 16, 1])
xt of size: torch.Size([128, 40, 1])
```

I would like to concatenate xt to rc along dimension 2 so that the final size of rc_xt is:

```py
rc_xt = torch.Size([128, 40, 2])
```

In short, I want to 'increase' the size of rc's dimension 1 (16) to 40 -- through any means, even just repeating elements -- and then concatenate them both along dimension 2.

I have tried to google how to do this but I cannot get it working no matter what I do, I'm a little confused about how to go about doing this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Increasing" the size of `rc` can be done simply by [padding](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pad).
For instance, you can pad it by zeros:

```py
p_rc = nnf.pad(rc, (0, 0, 0, xt.shape[1]-rc.shape[1], 0, 0), 'constant', 0)
```

Once you have a padded version of `rc` you can concat:

```py
rc_xt = torch.concat((p_rc, xt), dim=-1)
```